# How to modify unsupervised dedupe rule

Tags: duplicate-contacts

In some of my CiviCRM database, i have contacts who share the same email.
I don't want people to modify the wrong contact when filling a public anonymous form.

To avoid that, I'd like the unsupervised dedupe rule for individual to be Email + First Name.

When i go to the UI (`/civicrm/contact/deduperules?reset=1&action=browse`) i see it's not possible to change the default rule.
Is there any problem to expect if i disable the default rule in the database by setting `is_active = 0` and create a new unsupervised rule ?

**EDIT**

I see there is no `is_active` field so i guess i will have to either delete, either changed it to a `General` type of rule.

The question is the same - is there any problem to expect ?

Comment: On top of @John's answer, I recommend this great post: https://civicrm.org/blogs/spidersilk/understanding-civicrm-dedupe-rules

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On our site we simply created a new rule, and chose the 'Unsupervised' option when creating it.

[image]

That creates the rule, and marks it as the default 'Unsupervised' one. The old default is downgraded to a 'General' rule. If it was a built-in rule then it stays 'reserved' so you can't edit it.

I don't think there's any need to delete them, or fiddle in the database =]